# Tcp Socket + send() error #10054

Tags: windows, sockets, windows-mobile, winapi

I am working on a sample application which sends file to other device. I have 2 buttons on my window, one is to send and other is to stop file transfer. Send; send the file to destination and Stop: stops the sending process.

When I send the multiple files to destination, all files reach destination properly. But if I click  send and stop repeatedly for 3 to 4 times (ie initially I click send then suddenly within no time I click stop.  I will continue this process for 3 to 4 times). 
Then if I try to send the multiple files then, it will send first file and when it send the 2 file I get error #10054 in the function Send().

I am using non-blocking socket by:
u_long i = 1;
ioctlsocket(sockt, FIONBIO, &i);

in the destructer I am closing the scoket.

please help he to solve this problem.

Comment: 10054 = connection reset by peer. Means the other side has closed connection

Comment: Is there any way to avoid this from my side? This happens only if I try to send and stop repeatedly for 3 to 4 times.

Comment: Would be better if you can post your code or can give some info. Do you create new connection for every file transfer which you do? Also, what about the server? Is it a standard one or written by you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, it seems to me like the problem is on the peer end.
It may not manage the connections properly. For instance, there might be more than one connection at the time (more than one active socket, like one stopped lingering and a new one just being created) and the other side program not being aware of that.

Comment: Thanks for the replay,
I read that closesocket() doesn’t close the socket immediately after calling the close socket. It just initiates the close operation. How to overcome from this problem.

Comment: This is not a problem. This is normal. Your server should support multiple connections, for exactly this reason.

Comment: Is it is right way to reestablish connection (again create socket and connect) with remote device? If I do it, any problem comes?